# How to return the title instead of the post ID in a WordPress Form Plugin Field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this custom hook from the Formidable plugin which gets the value from one field and copies it over to a second field.

More Details https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/frm_validate_field_entry/#kb-change-the-value-in-a-field

The code works as expected but instead of returning the exact copied value of the field, it displays it's ID.

I tried replacing `$_POST['item_meta'][140]` with `get_the_title( $_POST['item_meta'][140] );` but now there's no value in the field.

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'copy_my_field', 10, 3);
function copy_my_field($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
  if ( $posted_field->id == 128 ) { //change 25 to the ID of the field to change
    $_POST['item_meta'][$posted_field->id] = $_POST['item_meta'][140]; 
//Change 20 to the ID of the field to copy  }
  return $errors;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but check that `$posted_value` doesn't contain the `$_POST` data instead of using the `$_POST` superglobal.

Comment: All I want is to get the title not the id which is given by this ```$_POST['item_meta'][20];```

Comment: I think I just understood what you meant so I changed it to ```[$posted_field->name]``` but still didn't display the name. Change is for ```id``` to ```name```. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, and what you're saying... the `$_POST['item_meta'][140]` is the post ID of the post you want to find the title of?

This is not tested, but if `$_POST['item_meta'][140]` is the post ID, then this will get the title.

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'copy_my_field', 10, 3);
function copy_my_field($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value) {
    if ($posted_field->id == 128) {
        //get the post object from post ID
        $post = get_post($_POST['item_meta'][140]);
        $_POST['item_meta'][$posted_field->id] = $post->post_title;
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have managed without your answer. I adapted it for ```get_term_by()``` which got the issue fixed. The id was for a taxonomy not a post. ```add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'copy_my_field_ptype', 10, 3);
function copy_my_field_ptype($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value) {
    if ($posted_field->id == 128) {
        //get the term object from term ID
        $term_c = get_term_by('id', $_POST['item_meta'][140], 'country');
        $_POST['item_meta'][$posted_field->id] = $term_c->name;
    }
    return $errors;
}```